# Generating functions combinatorical problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

In how many ways can you choose $10$ balls, of a pile of balls containing $10$ identical blue balls, $5$ identical green balls and $5$ identical red balls?

My solution (not sure if correct, would like to have input):

Define generated function:

$$\begin{align}
A(x) & =(x^0+x^1+x^2+...+x^{10})(x^0+x^1+x^2+...+x^5)(x^0+x^1+x^2+...+x^5) \\
& ={1-x^{11} \over 1-x}\cdot \left({1-x^6 \over 1-x}\right)^2 \\
& =(1-x^{11})(1-2x^6+x^{12}) \cdot {1 \over (1-x)^3} \\
& =(1-2x^6-x^{11}+x^{12}+2x^{17}-x^{23})\cdot \sum_{n=0}^∞ {n+2 \choose 2} \cdot x^n.
\end{align}$$

We look for the coefficient of $x^{10}$, so we get:

$$a_{10}=1 \cdot {10+2 \choose 2}-2\cdot {4+2 \choose 2}=36.$$

This seems incorrect (sadly I'm terrible in 'ordinary combinatorics' so I'm not sure how to calculate this 'regularly'). I would love to get input and hints.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The $x^{23}$ comes from $x^{11} \cdot x^{12}$.

Comment: Your number is correct.  There are $6$ different possibilities for the number of green and red balls each, any number from $0$ to $5$.  All combinations of these possibilities are allowed.  So $6\times 6=36$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Why do you 'ignore' the number of blue balls?

Comment: The blue balls act as filler.  First decide how many green and red balls to choose, and then fill in the remaining spots with blue balls.  It just so happens in this problem that this method works, because the smallest number of green and red balls we can choose is $0$, and we have enough blue balls to fill in the remaining $10$ spots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s one elementary approach. As you see, it confirms your result.

Let $b,g$, and $r$ be the numbers of blue, green, and red balls chosen to make up a set of $10$ balls. You’re looking for the number of solutions in non-negative integers to the equation $$b+g+r=10\;,\tag{1}$$ subject to the condition that $g\le 5$ and $r\le 5$. (You also have to have $b\le 10$, but that imposes no additional constraint when the sum is to be $10$.) Without the upper bounds this is a standard [stars-and-bars problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29) whose solution is

$$\binom{10+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{12}2\;.$$

However, this count includes solutions with too many green or red balls. Let $g'=g-6$; then there is a bijection between solutions to $$b+g'+r=4\tag{2}$$ in non-negative integers and solutions to $(1)$ for which $g>5$. Thus, we need only count solutions to $(2)$ to get the number of solutions to $(1)$ with $g>5$. This is another stars-and-bars problem, and the answer is

$$\binom{4+3-1}{3-1}=\binom62\;.$$

Similarly, there are $\dbinom62$ solutions to $(1)$ that have $r>5$. There are no solutions that exceed the upper limits on both $g$ and $r$, so the number of solutions to $(1)$ that satisfy all of the conditions is

$$\binom{12}2-2\binom62=36\;.$$

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough explanation. I need to practice more on the inclusion-exclusion principle. I have a small question for you: about the binomial coefficient: What's the correct formula? ${1 \over (1-x)^k}= \sum_{n=0}^∞ {n+k-1 \choose k-1}...$ or $=\sum_{n=0}^∞ {n+k-1 \choose k}...$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ohad: You’re welcome. $$\frac1{(1-x)^k}=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}x^n=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n+k-1}nx^n\;.$$